# Gdansk Knight to you

Tags: riddle, word, cryptic-clues, anagram, haiku

More than surprising, 
and slippery to the core, 
I give resistance.

I hide my secrets, 
until you come upon me, 
revealing myself.

Evening stars of,  
transcendental quality, 
illuminate me.

Unravelling the,  
centrally coiled hemisphere,  
signifying me.

The source of gold eggs,  
sifting sibilant language,  
giving birth to me.

I'm from the third sphere,  
said the Swiss eponymous,  
for my sixth one.

Comment: what is densa ?

Comment: @JAVY [Densa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Densa)

Comment: The Densa tag's been removed - that's fine. I only put it on at the last moment as after adding Haiku, Anagram, Riddle i looked for something beginning with D and couldn't resist adding Densa.

Comment: ... an incorrect tag being there fits with the most common sense of the answer - all the answerers below know the meaning of the answer which is most hinted at in the haiku.

Comment: A loose string of associations: Gdansk knight = Danzig knight = dancing night. Probably not relevant here, though.

Comment: Added verse three. @Bolo - the anagram is from the correct place but the two words need 'translated' first.

Comment: Added three verses.

Comment: I am fairly confident this is something based on Euler. "Slippery to the core" - Euler (Oiler); transcendental numbers, coils (spiral, nautilus), Swiss, etc... I'm just having a hard time figuring out how it fits. Hope this helps trigger something for someone else, or @Tom can tell me if I am totally off. I also though the "sibilant language" could be integral symbols (based off the old "long S" symbol).

Comment: Euler sounds promising.

Comment: Verse 1 line 1 should be helpful.

Comment: Just loose thoughts about knights connected with Gdańsk: Blizbor was a knight (from a fairytale) there is a street in Gdańsk named after. Zawisza Czarny was more famous (and a real one) and there is a ship called SY Zawisza Czarny stationing in Gdańsk. In some 1308 Gdańsk was captured by Teutonic Order (knights) for some 150 years. That's it for the literal connections of knights and Gdańsk city :)

Comment: Interesting Gdansk Knight history. I'm afraid this title clue isn't the most helpful. An indirect anagram - it's an anagram of the answer - gives someone who could be a Knight from the relevant country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are a

> SPOILER.

The giveaway (if this is right) was actually Tom's comment that

> "an anagram of the answer gives someone who could be a Knight from the relevant country"

because that suggested

> looking for anagrams of SIR POLE.

Anyway, here are explanations of the verses (some with thanks to Tom for providing pointers in comments to things I'd missed; I'm leaving in my own half-baked thoughts even where they were wrong).

More than surprising,
and slippery to the core,
I give resistance.

> A spoiler gives away the otherwise **surprising** plot of a book or movie. At the centre of "sp**oil**er" we find **oil**, which is slippery. A spoiler on a car provides **resistance** to airflow and hence turbulent rather than laminar flow in a particular region, which reduces overall drag by some means I don't understand. *Edited to add*: OP indicates that I'm misunderstanding the first line and need to "translate symbolically", and after further prodding I finally get it: it's a reference to the SO markup for spoilers, `>!`. So `>` is "more than" and `!` is "surprising".

I hide my secrets,
until you come upon me,
revealing myself.

> This would apply pretty well to book/movie spoilers, but I think it's actually referring to the spoiler-hiding mechanism we have here. Spoilering a paragraph like this one you're reading right now **hides** its secrets but when you **move your cursor over it** it **reveals** itself.

Evening stars of,
transcendental quality,
illuminate me.

> Currently baffled by this. Does "transcendental" refer to transcendental numbers? (See the sixth verse, below.) Perhaps -- though this is rather a stretch -- we're taking the middle of Hesperus (Venus as the "**evening star**") and inserting "oil" (as in an **illuminating** oil lamp) to yield SPOILER. But what's transcendental about that? And why "evening star**s**", plural, in that case? And why only the middle of "Hesperus"? I think it's just coincidence that this construction works. *Edited to add*: yes, it's coincidence; OP's intention was that "evening stars" indicates **evenly spaced** letters: S**P**O**I**L**E**R yielding PI and E or $\pi$ and $e$, both transcendental.

Unravelling the,
centrally coiled hemisphere,
signifying me.

> SPOILER is almost an anagram of (found by **unravelling**) the **central** letters of "c**oile**d" and "hemi**sp**here". Perhaps "cent**r**ally" is referring to itself too, which would give us the missing "r". *Edited to add*: OP indicates that the actual intention was OILE from "centrally coiled" plus SPR from "hemisphere" (i.e., half of SPHERE).

The source of gold eggs,
sifting sibilant language,
giving birth to me.

> Currently baffled by this. The story of the goose that laid **golden eggs** is first found in Aesop, whose name has a lot of letters in common with SPOILER, but I don't see how to do anything useful with that. And "goose" in French is "oie" which also has a lot of letters in common with SPOILER, but I don't see what to do with that either. *Edited to add*: OP indicates that "a source of gold or eggs" might have been a better L1 and that we're looking for a computer language here, and after a bit more prompting from OP because I was stupid this is of course ORE/ROE plus LISP.

I'm from the third sphere,
said the Swiss eponymous,
for my sixth one.

> **Sixth letter** is E, so maybe this is a reference to the transcendental number *e*, **named for** the **Swiss** mathematician Euler. Not sure about the "third sphere"; perhaps there's some fanciful remark Euler made about *e*. (I guess it's the third *celestial* sphere, though what that is depends on whose geocentric model you use and whether you count from the inside or the outside.)  *Edited to add*: nope, that's all wrong; OP indicates that actually "the third sphere" = 1/3 of SPHERE = SP, plus "said the Swiss eponymous" = sounds-like a Swiss person after whom things are named = sounds-like Euler = OILER.

Comment: Very nice and yes this is it!   
i1 Y1 - genafyngr flzobyyvpnyyl. i3 tvirf 3 yrggref va erthyne cbfvgvbaf. i4 urzv vf sbe unys bs gur arkg yrggref. i5 znlor V fubhyq unir jevggra 'n fbhepr bs tbyq be rttf' & gura vg vf n pbzchgre ynat. i6 Y6 guveq vf 1/3 bs yrggref

Comment: Thanks. Still confused about a couple of bits, as you'll see.

Comment: Great additions - thanks! i1 Y1  - zngu naq Ratyvfu (be purff) flzobyf sbe 'zber guna'  'fhecevfvat'. i5 jnf znlor abg n terng pyhr ohg gur Y1 vf ber/ebr naq gura (nf lbh tbg, ohg nabgure ynathntr)  juvpu V gubhtug znl vf znlor cebabhaprq jvgu 'f' fbhaq creuncf?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan what language are you using to converse or has my computer gone haywire :)

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks, Tom, and sorry for being obtuse. @Sikorski Tom is obscuring his comments with ROT13 (google it) so that casual readers aren't needlessly spoiled.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - perfect! When I started PSE I used the first line to remember how to create the answer to this - and also I discovered rot13 gbb.

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I just happen to come check this right after it was solved, and I'll be the first to say... I'm really glad I didn't spend more time on this because I'd have never gotten it.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's

> Electricity

More than surprising

> Electricity can give you a shock

Slippery to the core

> Electricity flows and has current

I give resistance.

> Electrical resistance

I hide my secrets

> You can't see electricity

until you come upon me, 
revealing myself.

> But you can see its effects when you switch appliances on.

Not sure about the connection to the title,

> but remove the elec and Tricity is in Gdańsk.

Comment: Some very good points here - especially connecting ElecTricity with Gdansk. This is a different path though. The answer does have someting to do with a Knight from Gdansk but not so specific and then needs anagrammed. You have used the answer well in your answers.

Comment: @LiamH Actually Gdańsk, Sopot and Gdynia are cities forming the Tricity, so Tricity is not in Gdańsk but Gdańsk is in Tricity. Just for correctness sake.

Answer (score 3):

For the first two parts, it would nicely match any

> Carnivorous plant

But the third part is not explained. Note that

> Transcendental probably refers to transcendental numbers such as $\pi$, but I can't find anything else related to numbers here.

**Old answer**

Maybe

> Quicksand

More than surprising,
and slippery to the core,
I give resistance.

> Definitely surprising, slippery when trod upon, and you won't let me go

I hide my secrets,
until you come upon me,
revealing myself.

> I can't tell until I'm stuck in there

I can't explain the title though.

Comment: The title ( I think titles' are allowed a bit of leeway) is probably easier once the answer is found. If you like numbers could try the  third verse which was added after your post.

Comment: Correct on the transcendental numbers - and you have one of these.

Answer (score 3):

Are you :

> A snail?

More than surprising, and slippery to the core, I give resistance.

> The shell is resistant, but the animal is slippery inside. Plus this is a surprising animal.

I hide my secrets, until you come upon me, revealing myself.

> Noone know what is in a snail shell, until you pick it up and look inside.

Plus for the title

> This city, Gdansk (title) kinda looks like a snail upside down, and the knight might refer to snail horns.
>  [image]

This answer is densa approved :D

Comment: This is a really memorable and ingenious answer - comparing the city to a snail and then snail horns is pataphorical! You could try again with 'More than surprising' maybe splitting it into two parts and writing these down shortly.

Answer (score 2):

I have a meaning the the part that @fffred lacks. 
I think it could be:

> your mirror image

I hide my secrets, 
until you come upon me, 
revealing myself.

> the mirror itself doesn't show much, until you stand in front of it revealing your own image.

Guess we can combine this wif @fffred's answer to make a...

> sand mirror? :D

EDIT: Could it be...

> The sunset, night?
>  Hides stars, moon, and planets (evening stars) until it's time for it.
>   OR even...DARKNESS/Light? which hides things until light comes

FINAL EDIT: gonna give up if I don't get it right this time, after having read a bit about Gdansk history :D

> Castle, fortress, city-walls or the fortress door,  because...
>  They give ressitance againts enemies. Hide the city secrets, until you traspass them. For the location of the city, it might have some good starts illumination (I guess). You can hide yourself when desired, is conected with the Teutonic Knights who tried to invade the city...

Comment: Nice - there is something else which hides things until ...

Comment: Check edit pls :D

Comment: These are interesting and very good thoughts. The one I'm looking for though is something else which hides things - when desired.

Comment: Dunno if you get notifications of my updates, I comment so you check it, just in case

Comment: Thanks - yes - I get updates automatically since was question asker. Your updates give surprisingly good answers to the hints! Still there are specific answers to e.g. the 3 lines in verse one, a theme for verse 2 and for verse 3 something again specific which I hope which provide a certain answer.

Comment: Damn, I'm too bad for this :D. Hopefully my thoughts can help some1 else

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38742/discussion-between-tom-and-mario-garcia).

Answer (score 2):

How About:

> Diamond

More than surprising, and slippery to the core, I give resistance.

> Diamonds are great electrical insulator, the carbon making up a diamond can also be slippery when in Graphite form

I hide my secrets, until you come upon me, revealing myself

> Diamonds are hidden deep in the Earth, and need to be mined to be revealed

Evening stars of, transcendental quality, illuminate me.

> Diamonds are checked for impurities

From the comment made by @Tom on the question

> The tags all started with letters that could spell out HARD, and diamond is one of the hardest natural materials

---

**Old Answer**
How about

> Fireflies

More than surprising, and slippery to the core, I give resistance.

> The bugs are slippery when squashed

I hide my secrets, until you come upon me, revealing myself

> At night, they are hard to see until the light is turned on, or revealed

Evening stars of, transcendental quality, illuminate me.

> The lights can be thought of like little stars in the night

To explain the "dancing night"

> The fireflys dance and illuminate their lights at night

---

**Old(er) Answer**
Going off from @fffred and @MarioGarcia

Could it be

> Glass

More than surprising, and slippery to the core, I give resistance.

> Things will slide on glass when you don't expect it (black ice is like glass), and electricity will not flow through glass.

I hide my secrets, until you come upon me, revealing myself

> Glass is see through, hidden, until you run into it, then you know its there

Comment: These are nice posts with some very good answers. You could try a different meaning for transcendental.

Comment: The diamond answer is almost convincing - I never thought f it as a possibility! I'm not sure how it is 'More than' surprising - though I agree it would be surprising if I was given one. Also nice extra solution for HARD though this was just me trying to complete HAR and sorry it wasn't a clue - though the little bit about originally having a bad tag has some relevance to the answer. Diamond is very fitting though I think there is another answer which is more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer: Are you

> the Moon

More than surprising,

> Not sure on this one

and slippery to the core,

> Moon rock is an excellent lubricant

I give resistance.

> Not sure here either

I hide my secrets, 
until you come upon me, 
revealing myself.

> Dark Side of the Moon isn't visible from Earth, so we didn't know what was up there until we landed there and got to see it for ourselves

Evening stars of, 
transcendental quality, 
illuminate me.

> The Moon appears luminous due to reflected sunlight.

Comment: A good reply - especially the dark side of the moon. You could look at the first line by itself and that could give the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is it just

> **Euler**?

Verse 1

> Slippery to the core: Euler is said like "oiler"
> I give resistance: Euler wrote several formulae on [fluid dynamics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_equations_(fluid_dynamics)) (which would deal with resistence)

Verse 2

> Not sure

Verse 3

> Transcendental numbers $\pi$ and $e$ are used in [Euler's **identity**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity), and Euler worked with $e$ quite a bit in general (which is why it's known as [Euler's number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)), though he didn't discover it).

Verse 4

> This fits [Euler spiral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral) pretty well, though I'm not sure they're hemispheres.

Verse 5

> Russia was the source of [Fabergé eggs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faberg%C3%A9_egg), and Russian is a more sibilant language than most (having three or four sibilant sounds vs. most which have two, though one did/does have 27) and Euler attended a Russian academy, helping "give birth" to his mathematical intuition. He also continued to live there, apparently, until his death).

Verse 6

> Your sixth verse mentions being from Earth, the third "sphere" (rock, anybody?) from the sun, and Euler is Swiss, and though Swiss isn't a language, Euler is a swiss name

Comment: Answer's not perfect... And I'm having a hard time correlating with the title.

Comment: Euler is only clued from verse 6 though has connection with verse 3 as you have shown.

Comment: @Tom I'm sure I've bounced around the answer with all the stuff I've gone through, I think I'm just missing. The obvious interpretation for the first line is "shocking," but the one thing Euler seemed *not* to really affect much was electricity stuff, from what I'm seeing. Maybe I'm putting too much on Euler... But some of these other things seem to be pointing at it, too.

Comment: @Tom Ohh, Euler is only the 6th verse, I get it....